# Generate start and ending datetimes in UTC based on a PST date

Tags: php

I am taking in a parameter that is a date in PST timezone which will be in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD" (e.g. "2011-08-15").  This parameter is optional.  I have 2 questions that I've been struggling with.

I need to calculate the start and end datetime in **UTC** for this date.

So if the inputted date is `2011-08-15`, I want to get the start and end datetimes:

`2011-08-15 07:00:00`

`2011-08-15 06:59:59`

(These are essentially the beginning and end of day)

Second, is to handle the case when the date is not passed in. I want to default to the current PST date them and start from there.  So if the current datetime is `2011-08-01 10:00:00`, I want to get the same start and end datetimes similar to the first scenario except it's based on the inputted date.

`2011-08-01 07:00:00`

`2011-08-01 06:59:59`

I've been pulling my hair out dealing with date and datetime conversions. I'm sure I'm missing something super straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the date and assume PST timezone:

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-08-15", new DateTimeZone("PST"));
```

Change the timezone to UTC: (this does the all conversions for you)

```
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Calculate start and end. Start is our $date and end is $date + 1 day

```
$start = $date;
$end = clone $date;
$end->modify("+1 day"); // now $end is $start + 1 day
```

Print start/end:

```
printf("start: %s, end: %s\n", $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $end->format('Y-m-d Hi:s'));

// this prints start: 2011-08-15 07:00:00, end: 2011-08-16 07:00:00
```

For the last part of your questions, you can easily compare two dates:

```
if ($date > new DateTime()) { // if $date is after now
     // do something
}
```

So you could do something like that:

```
if ($date > new DateTime()) { 
    $date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

If you don't much like the OO syntax you could also use the function aliases:

```
$date = date_create(...);
date_format($date, ...);
date_modify($date, ...);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks this is really thorough. After reading your answer, I realized I had a mistake in my question. I don't want +1 day, I actually want the start and end dates on the SAME day, e.g. `2011-08-15 07:00:00` and `2011-08-15 06:59:59`

Comment: I don't understand how you determine the *end*, but given your examples I would say that you could simply use `$end->modify("- 1 minute")`

Comment: I guess I could do a `$end->modify("+1 day")` followed by a `$end->modify("-1 minute")`? Or perhaps just a single `$end->modify("+11 hours and 59 minutes")`?

Answer (score -1):

Use [setTimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.settimezone.php) function

Working example (I'm not in PST timezone, so I have to set it explicitly)

```
$date_input = "20011-09-15";
//$date_input = null; //That will emulate no-input case
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles"); //if you are in PST, you don't need this line
$date_start = new DateTime($date_input);
$date_end = new DateTime($date_input);
$date_end->modify("+1 day"); 

/*$date_start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
$date_end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));*/

//end of date is equal to start of the next day.
//But, if you need something like 2011-08-11 23:59:59 add $date_end->modify('-1 second')
$date_start->setTime(0,0,0);
$date_end->setTime(0,0,0);

echo "Date Start PST:".$date_start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>";
echo "Date End PST:".$date_end->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>";

//UTC is equal to London time. Almost :)
$date_start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone ('Europe/London'));
$date_end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone ('Europe/London'));

echo "Date Start UTC:".$date_start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>";
echo "Date End UTC:".$date_end->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>";
```